# How to pass data from one page to another?

Tags: javascript, html, html-framework-7

I'm using Framework7 on my website. I'm working on a register form with 5 register stages (pages). When I navigate from one page to another I do the following, for example:

```
app.views.main.router.navigate('/registerB/', { context: { email: fEmail} });
```

In the next page (in this case, `registerB`), how can I access the data (`email`) ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `app.views.main.router.currentRoute.context.email`?

Comment: @GrafiCode thanks for the response - in my case if I retrieve `app.views.main.router` it's undefined